# How can I preview photos from camera on laptop?

Tags: troubleshooting, file-format, preview

When I import photos to my laptop, windows 7 they are saved in a folder by month. When then clicking on the folder it opens up the individual photos but they all show a 'flower'symbol and I have no idea what the photo is of, unless I right click for a preview, which is not workable with many photos per folder! How do I get to see a small preview of all photos by folder in  one go? Thanks

[image]

Comment: Search this site for *tethering*, you will find many solutions to do this.

Comment: Are we talking RAW files here? Windows 7 doesn't natively support displaying previews of most raw files in the file Explorer.  In some cases you can download codec packs to enable this.

Answer (score 4):

Two possibilities that I can think of.

1. If you are shooting RAW, then you may need to download the [Microsoft Camera Codec Pack for Windows 7](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829) which will allow Windows to create thumbnail images as previews
2. You may simply need to change a folder view setting:

   - Open Windows Explorer
   - Click on Organize >Folder and Search options
   - On the "View" tab, uncheck the "Always use icons, never thumbnails" option

As vclaw commented, you also need to set the view option for the folder to medium, large or extra-large icons.  List, small icons and other options will show the "flower" icon in place of the actual image thumbnails

[image]

Comment: You may also have to change the view for that folder. ie set it to medium icons/large icons. If set to small icons, it won't show thumbnails.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting Adobe Lightroom or a similar program, Your dSLR came with a similar application, ViewNX2 for Nikon cameras.
Lr is a great program with many catalog features in addition to the Develop module. Lr will also allow you to shoot tethered.
BTW: You should ONLY be shooting RAW or "RAW + jpg".

Answer (score -3):

I take it you're not familiar with computers in the least. So let's back up a bit.  Each image is one file; presumably what you're looking at is a list of files in a "folder" that you copied to your computer's drive.

First thing: that's a default symbol for the app that your OS expects to be able to use to open each file.  Right-click and select "Open With..." to see what app is currently associated with the image files.

Next, read your camera manual and check your settings to find out what kind of file (JPEG, RAW, other) you're currently saving your images in.  Then get yourself an application off the net which can open and display the files.  The reason you can't view the "thumbnails" in the Windows Explorer window is the same reason you can't open the files -- not the right app.

Comment: There's no need to make assumptions about the OP's familiarity with computers generally just because he's not familiar with this one aspect.

Comment: @Caleb That's hardly "One aspect."  Not understanding the connection between icon and application is damned basic for anyone who knows more than how to log in and read yahoo mail.   Not to mention that4 days later he hasn't even bothered to come back and check his question.